# Dirichlet Theorem and Siegel-Walfisz Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Siegel-Walfisz Theorem states that, for $\gcd(a,b)=1$ $$\sum_{\substack{\\ p\le x \\p\equiv b\pmod a}}\log p=\dfrac{x}{\phi(a)}+O\left(\dfrac{x}{\log^C x}\right)$$
Then we take $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}$ to the equation and obtain infinity for the right-handed side, and hence, the left-handed as well. I think this proved Dirichlet Theorem that there exist infinitely many primes of the form $an+b$ in which $\gcd(a,b)=1$; because if there is only finitely many primes of that form their products won't be infinity.

Is it okay to conclude like this?

Comment: Sure. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yes, you can conclude like that, but it's a bit like concluding Euclid's theorem from the Chebyshev bounds.